Algorithm to extract overlapping range
Have an array of Pressures (hundreds) initialized like this:
class Pressure
{
    public double Low;
    public double Hi;
};

Pressure[] PressuresA = new[]  { 
    new Pressure { Low = 10.5, Hi = 16.5 }, 
    new Pressure { Low = 11.2, Hi = 11.4 }, 
    new Pressure { Low = 10.3, Hi = 17.5 }
};

Pressure[] PressuresB = new[]  { 
    new Pressure { Low = 10.5, Hi = 16.5 }, 
    new Pressure { Low =  8.1, Hi = 10.4 }, 
    new Pressure { Low = 10.8, Hi = 11.3 }
};

Looking for a function that return a Pressure object with a Low / Hi as the overlapping values of all elements in the array. If at least one element is outside the overlapping range, the returning Low / Hi must be 0 / 0.
The above PressureA must return 11.2, 11.4
The above PressureB must return 0, 0
Any suggestions?
Thanks
Danny

Well, if there is an overlapping range, I'd expect the result "low" to be the highest of all the "low" components, and the result "high" to be the lowest of all the "high" components. Then you just need to check whether the resulting low is less than or equal to high... if it is, that's the result, otherwise it's 0/0.

We can find maximum among all the Low and minimum among all the High and check if it is a valid range:
using System.Linq;

...

var pressures = PressuresA;

double maxLow = pressures.Max(item => item.Low);
double minHi = pressures.Min(item => item.Hi);

Pressure result = maxLow > minHigh
  ? new Pressure() // invalid range
  : new Pressure() { Low = maxLow, Hi = minHi };

